# Auth retornando sempre false

Tags: laravel-5, auth

Bom estou desenvolvendo um `login` próprio e nele tenho outros `campos` e outra `tabela`, tudo vai perfeitamente porém sempre volta resultado `false`.

Alterei o arquivo `Authenticatable.php` dentro de  `\Illuminate\AuthZAuthenticatable` para :

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
   return $this->password; //anteriormente era assim
    return $this->Senha;
}
```

No meu arquivo `auth.php` dentro de `config` está assim:

```
return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'pessoas',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'pessoas',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'pessoas',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'pessoas' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Pessoa::class,
    ],

     'pessoas' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'pessoas',
     ],
],


'passwords' => [
    'pessoas' => [
        'provider' => 'pessoas',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
  ],
];
```

Meu `model Pessoa` está assim:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Pessoa extends Authenticatable
{
   use SoftDeletes;
   protected $fillable = [
    'NmPessoa',
    'CPF',
    'Email',
    'Senha',
    'Telefone',
    'DtNasc',
    'Sexo',
    'FglNewsLater',
    'FglStPessoa',
    'ObsPessoa',
    'FglADM',
    'FglCliente',
    'FglFuncionario',
    'Cidade',
    'Estado',
    'Bairro',
    'Rua',
    'Num',
    'Complemento',
    'CEP'
  ];

   protected $hidden = [
     'Senha', 'remember_token',
   ];

   protected $primaryKey = 'CdPessoa';
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  public function setPasswordAttribute($Senha)
  {
    $this->attributes['Senha'] = bcrypt($Senha);
  }
}
```

Em meu `controller AuthController` fiz assim:

```
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

  public function authenticate(Request $request)
  {
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('senha');


    dd(Auth::attempt(['Email' => $email, 'Senha' => $password]));

    if (Auth::attempt(['Email' => $email, 'Senha' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }
 }
}
```

E em meu HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="email" name="email" lass="form-control" id="email-modal" placeholder="E-mail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" id="password-modal" placeholder="Senha">
    </div>
    <p class="text-center">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Entrar</button>
    </p>
 </form>
```

Com tudo isto, o que poderá o causador do problema.

> Pensando aqui acho que poderia ser a parte de `senha` criptografada, eu salvo no banco ela bcrypt(Senha), ja tentei alterar esta parte o attempt() porém não funcionou e continuou dando false. Vale lembrar que eu tenho o usuário no banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa alterar o código que vem com o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), porque, ele tem diversas formas de implementação de `login` do ***usuário***, volte o que era antes e siga essa lógica.

Primeira coisa entre na pasta `config` arquivo `auth.php` e tem um array `providers` coloque dentro `model` a sua `classe` Pessoa.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Pessoa::class,
        ],
```

---

Crie no método de verificação um *instância* da ***classe*** `User`, e faça a pesquisa pelo, `email`, ou por qualquer campo (ou campos) que assim desejar e no final da expressão use `first()`. Se o resultado foi favorável e trouxe uma *instância* da ***classe*** `User`, utilize o método de autenticação pela *instância* da ***classe*** `User` (`Authenticate A User Instance`) `\Auth::login($find);` que é efetivado a autenticação do usuário, sendo muito parecido do comando `\Auth::attempt`, diferente, porque a responsabilidade de conferir os dados fica a cargo do desenvolvedor.

**Exemplo Simples:**

```
$user = new \App\Models\Pessoa();
$find = $user->where('Email', 'email@email.com')->first();

if ($find) // se encontrou o usuário
{
    //verifiando a senha texto enviado pelo form
    //comparando com hash gravado no banco
    if (\Hash::check($request->input('senha'), $find->Senha)) 
    {
        //autorizando o login do usuário.
        \Auth::login($find);
    }
}

return redirect('/home');
```

[Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) demonstra os outros meios de autenticação:

***Other Authentication Methods*** - Outros Métodos de Autenticação

- `Authenticate A User Instance` - Pela instância da classe `User`.
- `Authenticate A User By ID`- Pelo chave primária configurada na classe `User`.
- `Authenticate A User Once` - Autenticação por requisição (*esse não é o que precisa*).

Comment: Brother preciso das alterações, por exemplo minha instancia precisa ser pessoa, nao posso ter o user como principal

Comment: Brother é só fazer uma alteração na na pasta `config/auth.php` na chave `'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],` coloque o sua classe na chave `model`.

Comment: Ai utilizo seu codigo ? Model\User ?

Comment: Fiz a edição, e você utiliza o código que eu fiz ou faça a sua maneira, aquele método só precisa de uma instância que no seu caso é `pessoa`.

Comment: No caso o hash::check, ele mesmo ja faz o bycrypt da senha ?

Comment: Até a parte do find está funcionando porém na senha esta dando problema

Comment: no caso bycrypt é um `helper` do facade `Hash`, no facade você tem todas as opções.

Comment: Não sei como você gravou a senha precisa talvez gerar novamente. Acontece muito isso de confundir a senha.

Comment: sim, irei testa aqui, so um momento

Comment: estou tendo problemas ao salvar a senha com bcrypt, como devo fazer ? Sei que é outra pergunta :d

Comment: pega uma instância da classe `$p = Pessoa::find(1);` e depois `$p->Senha = bcrypt(123456);` e `$p->save();`

Comment: de forma automatica pelo model tem como ?

Comment: Faz um método e rode só pra gravar uma vez! depois se comenta a linha.

Comment: ok, so um minto

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema, na verdade tava dando errado pois eu gerei pessoalmente o hash, então nao estava batendo com o que tinha no banco de dados.

Comment: Por nada @RenanRodrigues