# Laravel 5.2: Multi autenticação sempre retorna false

Tags: php, laravel, autenticação, laravel-5.2

Sempre está retornando erro na hora de fazer o *login*, mesmo que os dados estejam corretos. Já vi vários tópicos sobre esse erro, mas nenhum resolveu o problema.

*CONTROLLER*

```
public function cadastro(Request $request)
{
    $dataForm = $request->all();

    $dataForm['password'] = bcrypt($dataForm['password']);

    $cliente = $this->cliente->create($dataForm);
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = ['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password];

    if(Auth::guard('cliente')->attempt($credentials)) {
        echo 'OK';
    } else {
        echo 'ERRO';
    }
}
```

*MODEL*

```
class Cliente extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'clientes';
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'sobrenome', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

*AUTH*

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'cliente' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clientes',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'clientes' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Cliente::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Estou criando a tabela sem *migration*, ou seja, direto no banco:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(id int auto_increment, 
                     nome varchar(50), 
                     sobrenome varchar(50), 
                     email varchar(50), 
                     password varchar(50), 
                     created_at datetime, 
                     updated_at datetime, 
                     primary key(id));
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está retornando?

Comment: Não retorna nenhum erro, é que sempre cai no else na hora de autenticar. Como se eu tivesse digitado os dados errados.

Comment: Eu já coloquei algo parecido: dá uma olhada nesse link resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162965/laravel-authatempt-sempre-retorna-false/162970#162970

Comment: Outro exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158409/auth-retornando-sempre-false/158424#158424 deve ser nas configurações os problemas de entrar no `else`

Comment: Chequei os exemplos, mas continua a mesma coisa. A autenticação na tabela users funciona normal, o problema é essa outra da tabela clientes.

Comment: Já tentou alterar a senha novamente e refazer o login?

Comment: Sim, acontece a mesma coisa. O email ele encontra no banco, o problema é comparar a senha digitada com a que ta no banco.

Comment: Cara, resolvi alterando o tamanho do campo do password no banco. Tinha colocado 50, e parece que é pequeno para o bcrypt, Troquei para 100 e agora tá comparando certinho. Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Coloque como resposta explicando o motivo e a solução.

Answer (score 0):

O *bcrypt* ocupa mais de 50 caracteres, então alterei o tamanho no banco para 100 e o problema foi resolvido!