# Autenticação Customizada Laravel com Postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql, autenticação

Criei um `custom` `provider`, chamado `CustomUserProvider`, extendi de `EloquentUserProvider` e trouxe os campos perfeito.

Porém o login não persiste

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['ususenha'];

    if ($plain == $this->hash($user->getAuthPassword())) {
        dd('Foi');
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Nesse código ele cai ali no `dd('Foi')` porém não loga e fiz um teste usando `MySQL` e funcionou, usando o `MySQL` funciona, mas com o `Postgres` não funciona.

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Só uma pergunta, porque criou um `Provider` que já existe? Qual os motivos que levaram você a fazer isso, porque já tem? Eu sei que são perguntas chatas, mas, eu acabo não entendo o motivo de replicar um código já existente!

Comment: Bom, eu preciso fazer um login com uma criptografia diferente das criptografias disponíveis no laravel, é uma criptografia desenvolvida pela galera na empresa, então, para não alterar os arquivos dentro de vendor eu criei um provider herdando as características do EloquentUserProvider que é o responsável por essa parte no laravel, porém notei que quando uso Postgres não funciona! Se eu conecto um banco mysql funciona...

Comment: Existe formas e formas de fazer isso, mas, você dizer que não precisava implementar outro código, porque, no Laravel eu posso checar a senha do jeito que eu quiser e com a instância da classe fazer login do usuário. Alguns exemplos: [exemplo1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148446/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-customizada-com-cpf-e-e-mail/151477#151477), [exemplo2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158409/auth-retornando-sempre-false/158424#158424) e esse diversos tipos [exemplo3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162965/laravel-authatempt-sempre-retorna-false/162970#162970).

Comment: continuando ... Então não precisa fazer um implementação dessa ... é uma dica só buscar o usuário pelas informações e com a instância dar um comando `Auth::login($user)` que funciona do mesmo jeito

Comment: Então, eu ja tentei fazer dessas formas, porém `Auth::login($user)` só volta `null`

Comment: Você tem que utilizar o mesmo mecanismo e a classe que vem no Laravel

Comment: Como assim? 

Abaixo segue meu código

`public function tentaLogar(Request $request)
    {
        $pessoa = User::where('usunome', $request->usunome)->first();
        
        if (sizeof($pessoa) > 0) {
            dd(Auth::login($pessoa));
            if ($this->hash($request->ususenha) === $pessoa->ususenha) {
                Auth::login($pessoa);

                return redirect($this->redirectTo);
            }

        }
 
    }`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86596/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-hanania-mizrahi).